# R: Association Rules (arules) not writing any rules - is my dataset too small?

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, arules, market-basket-analysis

I've read through Stack and various documentation online and I'm still not getting this to work.

I have a dataset of 5,368 transactions. They come in as an Excel sheet with a bunch of different columns - CustomerID, ItemID, and OrderID (see below, data comes in as it is shown from A1:C10).

I have 3 questions:

- Specifically what format does the data need to be in? I've tried reading it in using all 3 formats shown below. I can get read.transactions to read in the data in any of these formats, but when I go to run the apriori it just gives me 1 rule (or sometimes none). Even to get that one rule I have to set the confidence to .01 and the lhs is always blank.
- The most recent attempt I made, I used the format shown at row 21. I even cut out all the single transactions (row 23 & 24). I then ran this syntax:

```
sb<-read.transactions(file = "~/Downloads/sbasket.csv",sep = ",")
```

I think I even tried:

```
sb<-read.transactions(file = "~/Downloads/sbasket.csv", format="single",sep=",", cols=c(1,2))
```

- How big does your dataset need to be? My dataset is 5,368 rows, of which only 366 involve multiple transactions (so most lines in the data are like row 6 below), so roughly only 7% of my overall data has multiple item baskets. Is this why I am getting no rules? This is why I tried eliminating all single basket orders, but even that didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about 'arules,' but is it possible the problem is it's expecting a csv and you are loading an excel spreadsheet? Maybe try using the package 'openxlsx' to read the file first, then input it to read.transactions?

Comment: I don't think that's it. read.transactions reads the file in and parses it just fine, but it seems arules can't do anything with the data it's being given. If it was just the file extension I'd expect read.transactions to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

`arules` can read format 1 and 3. Use `summary(sb)` to check that the items are read-in correctly. Here is an example for your format 3:

```
trans_txt <- "13,19,20\n17\n1,\n16,17"
write(trans_txt, file = "trans.txt")

library("arules")
trans <- read.transactions("trans.txt", sep = ",")
summary(trans)

  transactions as itemMatrix in sparse format with
  4 rows (elements/itemsets/transactions) and
  6 columns (items) and a density of 0.2916667 

  most frequent items:
    17       1      13      16      19 (Other) 
     2       1       1       1       1       1 

  element (itemset/transaction) length distribution:
  sizes
  1 2 3 
  2 1 1 

  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.00    1.00    1.50    1.75    2.25    3.00 

  includes extended item information - examples:
  labels
  1      1
  2     13
  3     16

rules <- apriori(trans)
inspect(rules)

     lhs        rhs  support confidence lift count
[1]  {16}    => {17} 0.25    1          2    1    
[2]  {19}    => {20} 0.25    1          4    1    
[3]  {20}    => {19} 0.25    1          4    1    
[4]  {19}    => {13} 0.25    1          4    1    
[5]  {13}    => {19} 0.25    1          4    1    
[6]  {20}    => {13} 0.25    1          4    1    
[7]  {13}    => {20} 0.25    1          4    1    
[8]  {19,20} => {13} 0.25    1          4    1    
[9]  {13,19} => {20} 0.25    1          4    1    
[10] {13,20} => {19} 0.25    1          4    1
```